# HTML render issue - works in Mozilla Firefox, but not on Google Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox

The following Php file renders perfectly fine with Mozilla Firefox. However, when running the same on Google Chrome; result - It displays the entire HTML code instead of rendering it. Basically indicates that Google Chrome browser is unable to understand and display the HTML code.

> abc.php File

```
  <?php  
session_start();//session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages.  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>        
.... //some lines of code
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was

While Firefox browser parses and renders the HTML code.
Google Chrome isn't able to understand that the php file is a HTML code in itself.

Solution

> Placement of the DOCTYPE line as the FIRST LINE of the FILE

Hence the change is in the positioning of the DOCTYPE line indicating the type of document to be displayed on the browser.

> abc.php File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php  
session_start();//session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages.  
?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>        
.... //some lines of code
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't get why it is downvoted .Since I solved the issue with same solution. Where it was important to place the DOCTYPE line as the first line of the file

Comment: I have reverted to down vote, but start session before <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: `session_start` must come before any html output

Comment: you are not seeing any errors because you must have turned off error reporting in php. Or else, php will always complain about session errors if you print out something before starting session.

Comment: When session_start is put before the DOCTYPE, Chrome is not able to render it. So what should I do to ensure both PHP works as well as Chrome doesn't throw any rendering issue.

Comment: Error resolved. PHP wasn't installed properly on AWS EC2 installed and hence it wasn't getting executed. Kept DOCTYPE declaration as first line and php code later. It worked